# VideoJS event triggers in older version of Android 2.x

Tags: video.js

We are having trouble firing events on Android 2.x devices.  From our testing, Android 4.x and iOS 5/6 work correctly.  But on Android 2.x devices, we are sometimes getting the "end" event and sometimes we are getting the "start" event.

It says it has cross browser compatibility but anyone run into these issues?

Here are the relevant parts of the code

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.css">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/c/video.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="videoplayer" style="margin:0 auto; text-align:center;">
    <video id="video" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls autoplay preload="auto" width="300" height="300">
    </video>
  </div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {    
  _V_("video").ready(function() {

    var thePlayer = this;    
    var startVideo = function() {
            // do stuff
    };

    var endVideo = function() {
            // do stuff
    };
    thePlayer.addEvent("play", startVideo);
    thePlayer.addEvent("ended", endVideo);
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem.  I was able to reproduce it on a Android 2.2 and 2.3 emulator.  No events were firing on video playback because there was an error loading the video.

Issues (For Android 2.x devices):

- Playing a link from an HTTPS url was no working.  The link we were using was an Amazon Cloudwatch URL which linked to an Amazon S3 bucket.  When I changed the url to an HTTP vs HTTPS URL it worked.
- I had to remove the autoplay attribute on the video element.  Not sure why, but the video player in Android 2.x didn't like this.

Once I made these 2 fixes I was able to stream video on Android 2.x devices (as well as Android 4.x, iPhone and iPod)